# FATAL ERROR al lanzar una actividad en Android. SettingsActivity.class

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un problema al lanzar una actividad, me da este error.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: jhon.casique.baccus, PID: 2424
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jhon.casique.baccus/jhon.casique.baccus.controller.SettingsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at jhon.casique.baccus.controller.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:32)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Application terminated.

```
package jhon.casique.baccus.controller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import jhon.casique.baccus.R;


public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE = "jhon.casique.baccus.controller.SettingsActivity.EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE";

    //Views
    private RadioGroup mRadioGroup = null;


     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


         if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE).equals(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)){
             mRadioGroup.check(R.id.fit_radio);
         }
         else if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE).equals(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)){
             mRadioGroup.check(R.id.center_radio);
         }

         //Created here because I just need to have the buttons references to respond to events or when the user pressed it
         Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
         Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);

         cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
         saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.cancel_button:
                cancelSettings();
                break;
            case R.id.save_button:
                saveSettings();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void saveSettings() {
        Intent config = new Intent();
        if (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fit_radio) {
            config.putExtra(EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE, ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
        else if (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.center_radio) {
            config.putExtra(EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE, ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        }
        setResult(RESULT_OK, config);

        finish();
    }

    private void cancelSettings() {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        finish();
    }
}
```

Este es mi *SettingsActivity.java*, que es concretamente la actividad que quiero ejecutar.

```
package jhon.casique.baccus.controller;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import jhon.casique.baccus.R;
import jhon.casique.baccus.model.Wine;


public class WineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Model
    private Wine mWine = null;


    //Views
    private ImageView mWineImage = null;
    private TextView mWineNameText = null;
    private TextView mWineTypeText = null;
    private TextView mWineOriginText = null;
    private RatingBar mRatingBar = null;
    private TextView mWineCompanyText = null;
    private TextView mWineNoteText = null;
    private ViewGroup mWineGrapesContainer = null;
    private ImageButton mGoToWebButton = null;


    private static final int SETTINGS_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final String STATE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE = "jhon.casique.baccus.controller.WineActivity.STATE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE";
    private static final String TAG = WineActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wine);

        //Creating model
        mWine = new Wine(
                "Bembibre",
                "Tinto",
                R.drawable.bembibre,
                "Dominio de Tares",
                "http://www.dominiodetares.com/portfolio/bembibre/",
                "Este vino muestra toda la complejidad y la elegancia de la variedad Mencía. En fase visual luce un color rojo picota muy cobierto con tonalidades violáceas en el menisco. En nariz aparecen recuerdos frutales muy intensos de frutas rojas (frambuesa, cereza) y una potente ciruela negra asi como tonos florales de la gama de las rosas y violetas, vegetales muy elegantes y complementarios, hojarasca verde, tabaco y maderas aromáticas (sándalo) que le brindan un troque ciertamente perfumado",
                "El Bierzo",
                5);
        mWine.addGrape("Mencía");


        //Accessing views from the controller file.
        mWineImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wine_image);
        mWineNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wine_name);
        mWineTypeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wine_type);
        mWineOriginText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wine_origin);
        mRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.wine_rating);
        mWineCompanyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wine_company);
        mWineNoteText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wine_notes);
        mWineGrapesContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.grapes_container);
        mGoToWebButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.go_to_web_button);

        //Giving value to the views with the model
        mWineImage.setImageResource(mWine.getPhoto());
        mWineNameText.setText(mWine.getName());
        mWineTypeText.setText(mWine.getType());
        mWineOriginText.setText(mWine.getOrigin());
        mRatingBar.setRating(mWine.getRating());
        mWineCompanyText.setText(mWine.getCompanyName());
        mWineNoteText.setText(mWine.getNotes());

        //List grapes actualization.
        for (int i = 0; i < mWine.getGrapeCount(); i++) {
            TextView grapeText = new TextView(this);
            grapeText.setText(mWine.getGrape(i));
            grapeText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            mWineGrapesContainer.addView(grapeText);
        }

        //Buttons configuration.
        mGoToWebButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent webIntent = new Intent(WineActivity.this, WebActivity.class);

                webIntent.putExtra(WebActivity.EXTRA_WINE, mWine);

                startActivity(webIntent);
            }
        });

        //Image view configuration.
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE)) {
            mWineImage.setScaleType((ImageView.ScaleType) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(STATE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE));
        }

    }
    //Methods to create the menu settings image.
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId()== R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            settingsIntent.putExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE, mWineImage.getScaleType());
            startActivityForResult(settingsIntent, SETTINGS_REQUEST);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    //Method to create the new activity trow the menu.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SETTINGS_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ImageView.ScaleType scaleType = (ImageView.ScaleType) data.getSerializableExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE);
            mWineImage.setScaleType(scaleType);
        }
    }

    //Method for maintaining the user option to screen rotated.

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable(STATE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE, mWineImage.getScaleType());
    }
}
```

Y esta es la pantalla donde voy a realizar la actividad. Creo que el problema que está en la llamada `action_settings`, que está en la línea `WineActivity 122`.

He entendido que justamente hay un menú en mi `menu_main.xml` con ese nombre, pero también en el fichero *values*, se crea un archivo, `ids.xml`, que tiene la misma opción. Al presionar directamente *Crtl+Click* sobre la llamada, me lleva a este fichero, en vez de el que quiero que se inicie la actividad, al cambiarles de nombre, igual me da error, entonces no sé cómo hacer.

Comment: El error esta en tu linea SettingsActivity.java:32, verifica y si puedes dejar el codigo para poder ayudarte de mejor forma!

Comment: Estoy verificando, el error esta aqui

Comment: if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE).equals(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)) {
                 mRadioGroup.check(R.id.fit_radio);
         }
         else if
             (getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_WINE_IMAGE_SCALE_TYPE).equals(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)) {
                 mRadioGroup.check(R.id.center_radio);
         }

Comment: Pero, no se donde.

Comment: @Jhon deja tu codigo de las layout, el error lo marca efextivamente cuando intenta buscar la ID R.id.center_radio por favor

Answer (score 2):

Como te comente en tu pregunta, el error era en tu Activity en la linea 32 especificamente.

Tu declaras `private RadioGroup mRadioGroup = null;` y luego en el `onCreate` de tu Activity

```
 mRadioGroup.check(R.id.fit_radio);
```

Sin decirle antes a

```
mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rdgGrupo);
```

Comment: Creo que te amo! MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: @Jhon jajajaja saludos!

Comment: @Jhon recuerda reemplazar la Id de tu elemento en tu layout por R.id.rdgGrupo

Comment: Si si lo he hecho asi y todo a funcionado! MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

El problema es desplegado en el mensaje del `LogCat`:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   jhon.casique.baccus.controller.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:32)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

en SettingsActivity.java que sería esta línea:

```
 mRadioGroup.check(R.id.center_radio);
```

El problema es que la variable `mRadioGroup` esta definida pero no inicializada:

```
private RadioGroup mRadioGroup = null;
```

debes buscar el id dentro de tu layout `activity_settings.xml`

y obtener su instancia antes de llamar sus metodos:

```
mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogGrupo);
...
...
mRadioGroup.check(R.id.center_radio);
```